# Calculation of Probability

Tags: c, probability

I want to calculate the conditional likelihood of the occurence of each character in a string for the entire string length. Say str={madam},so P(m)= number of times m occurs/total number of m. However, for each character the total probability should sum to 1 i.e P(m)=1; P(a)=1 and so on. I am stuck up at this and would be obliged if the code below is modified to incorporate this.

Comment: Ummmm...where in your code are you computing a probability?

Comment: And for that matter, what is `getche()`?

Comment: I don't think you're dealing with "probabilty". "Frequency" might be a better term. You already know everything about your data, so there's nothing random going on.

Comment: Your indentation technique could see some improvement. Don't use `gets()`: it is impossible to use safely (and since December last year is no longer part of Standard C).

Comment: So,if you could kindly encorporte probability as I mentioned before that this is not the code for probability since I am stuck with it.How to go about it using this code?

Comment: @eznme You could have also indented "count++", but it's at least readable now. :D

@Jack: It is a function from `conio.h`: (Wikipedia): "getche - Reads a character directly from the console without buffer, but with echo."

Comment: @Gandaro thanks. missed that.

Comment: @user1214586 - What do you mean by "encorporate [sic] probability"?  I **have no idea** what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Gandaro - Cool, thanks. I didn't find anything in the manpages on my machine. I should have googled it before asking via comment

Answer (score 2):

Before you start programming you could/should think about what you are trying to compute. First read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram and then this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram . It will get you started on what it means to calculate the conditional frequency of n-grams (that's what you need)

Comment: Thank you for the link. The objective is similar to the N Gram computation.So,how to do the coding for this using what I have done already.

Comment: This is not easy. I recommend that you start with computing the Bigram matrix. If you get that one working you can generalize your program. To compute the Bigram matrix to a given set of strings first initialize the matrix with all zeros (the matrix's width and height matches the number of letters in your alphabet). Then you of-course iterate through all the strings in your string-set; for each string for each letter increment the entry in the matrix at coordinate (x,y) where x is your previous letter and y is your current letter. In the end you have to divide every entry by the column sum.

Comment: Is this similar to the forward algorithm?I mean does the forward algorithm in markov model does the same task as this one?Or is the Baum Welch algorithm?